# FRM-18108: Failed to load the following objects. Source Object: CALENDAR

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I am having below error on loading of each form having CALENDAR object. Can anybody guide steps to resolve this issue. I am very new to Oracle and no idea about the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Directory - that contains libraries you use - should be part of the FORMS_PATH (or its derivates) in MS Windows Registry or DEFAULT.ENV file (on the IAS) (or somewhere else, depending on your operating system and Oracle Forms versions).

Basically, you have to make it (the calendar) accessible to form that uses it.